# Convert .ppt to .pdf like we do in OpenOffice?

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, openoffice-impress

I want to covert .ppt file to .pdf file like OpenOffice do using its "Export" option.

Is there any OpenOffice API avaliable or is there any shell-command for converting it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running linux you can open a terminal and paste something like this:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf yourfile.ppt
```

Comment: **Thank you!** Very useful command. Furthermore, it supports several files just by adding file names separated with space. 

You can add 'alias'-shortcut with command:
`alias libre2pdf="libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to "print" and use the PDF "printer" to output the ppt as a pdf.
Note: There has to be a "PDF printer" installed to be able to do this...

Comment: Basically i want to directly convert .ppt file to .pdf file from command line or openoffice API

Comment: How to install "PDF printer"?

Comment: maybe you are looking for something like this: http://www.softinterface.com/Convert-PowerPoint/Convert-PowerPoint.htm
 - 
eventually transforming ppt to OpenOffice format and then use their API (which I'm not familiar with) could be an alternative solution.
 - 
A popular "PDF printer" is Adobe Acrobat. There are several other when searching for "free pdf writer" on google.